# Write Tasks in dedicated file, when writing SBT AutoPlugins

Tags: scala, sbt

I have written an SBT auto plugin `MyPlugin.scala`:

```
package com.abhi

import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
   object autoImport {
      val helloTask = taskKey[Unit]("says hello")
      val byeTask = taskKey[Unit]("bye task")
   }
   import autoImport._
   override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
      helloTask := {
         val dir = sourceManaged.value
         val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value
         val r = (runner in Compile).value
         val s = streams.value
         val rd = (resourceDirectory in Compile).value         
         val sd = (sourceDirectory in Compile).value
         println(s"Here to say hello $dir $cp $r $s $rd $sd")
      },
      byeTask := {
         val dir = sourceManaged.value
         val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value
         val r = (runner in Compile).value
         val s = streams.value
         val rd = (resourceDirectory in Compile).value         
         val sd = (sourceDirectory in Compile).value         
         println(s"Here to say bye $dir $cp $r $s $rd $sd")
      }      
   )
}
```

This works and I am able to use this plugin. However the implementation of `helloTask` and `byeTask` will be a little long, so I don't want to write the implementation inside `MyPlugin.scala`.

Instead, I want to create two separate files `HelloTask.scala` and `ByeTask.scala` and then write the respective implementations there.

I looked at the SBT documentation for [Custom Settings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Custom-Settings.html) and all examples always implement the tasks inside of the plugin itself.

How can I write the implementation of `helloTask` and `byeTask` outside of the `MyPlugin.scala` file? also how to share some logic between `HelloTask` and `ByeTask`.

The following lines are common between the two tasks and I want to write these only once

```
val dir = sourceManaged.value
val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value
val r = (runner in Compile).value
val s = streams.value
val rd = (resourceDirectory in Compile).value         
val sd = (sourceDirectory in Compile).value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating tasks implementation is a common good practice. It is mentioned in the [Tasks documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Tasks.html#Separating+implementations). You can write an implementation using `Def.task` macro:

```
def taskImpl(args: ...): Def.Initialize[Task[...]] = Def.task {
  ...
}
```

And then use it with different arguments to set different task keys:

```
override def projectSettings = Seq(
  taskA := taskImpl("A").value,
  taskB := taskImpl("B").value,
)
```

---

In your case you could do something like this:

```
def saySmthImpl(msg: String): Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] = Def.task {
  val dir = sourceManaged.value
  val cp = (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value
  val r = (runner in Compile).value
  val s = streams.value
  val rd = (resourceDirectory in Compile).value
  val sd = (sourceDirectory in Compile).value
  println(s"$msg $dir $cp $r $s $rd $sd")
}
```

You can keep this implementation in a separate file if you want. The in the plugin definition you can use it like this:

```
override def projectSettings = Seq(
  helloTask := saySmthImpl("Here to say hello").value,
  byeTask := saySmthImpl("Here to say bye").value,
)
```

You should keep in mind though, that accessing other settings or tasks with `.value` can be done only in certain scopes, like that `Def.task` or `Def.setting` or when setting keys with `:=`. This limits (or rather *directs*) the ways you can share logic between different tasks implementations.